# "std::regex" with C++11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying the C++ standard regex library. But it is throwing std::regex_error exception. No idea what is going wrong. I can use Boost regex or PCRE also.

But I thought of going with G++ provided regex module. But unable to make it work with even simple expressions. Don't worry about the unused variables, I started with a moderately complex expression which needed them. But now I have reduced it just to match a word.

Please check sample which is crashing here:

http://ideone.com/fork/58EV7v

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    const char *vals = "abcdef";
    unsigned long start;
    unsigned int off;
    unsigned int size;

    std::cmatch cr;
    std::regex rx("(\\w+)");
    std::regex_match(vals, cr, rx);
    std::cmatch::iterator it = cr.begin();
    while (it != cr.end()){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and explaining the problem clearly.

Comment: Are you perhaps using GCC v4.8? It has a *limited* regex implementation, to say the least.

Comment: ideone is using GCC 4.8, which doesn't implement regex.

Comment: I'm running 4.9.1 and it works.

Comment: Yes. I am using GCC 4.8.1. IDEONE is also using GCC 4.8. But it was crashing with GCC 4.6 as well.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar GCC v4.6 doesn't have a better regex implementation than v4.8. If you want to use `<regex>` I suggest moving to v4.9, or some other compiler, e.g. Clang.

Comment: What `throwing std::regex_error exception` are you getting, or is this just a compiler issue/question?

Comment: @Biffen I have to use GCC 4.6 as that is what we use for building  C++ modules that goes into production. Anyway I will go with Boost.Regex.

Comment: @sln Exception is thrown from regex_match (i.e. from the line std::regex_match(vals, cr, rx))

Comment: You can see here that it will not work with 4.8.1: http://ideone.com/iG0cS9  However, what I did was compile a regex class into a .dll/.so, with visual studio and/or gcc 4.8.1 on linux and used that.. Worked like a charm.